# Is instantiating a derived class only once bad OOP?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, instantiation

I have a class structure that intends to only have my derived classes instantiated only once each. This seems to me like bad OOP, since multiple instances would be identical and serve no purpose, so should I replace it?

**Context:**
I am in the process of building the foundations for a calculator application. I have an `Operator` class that `Multiplication`, `Addition`, etc. inherit from. I am using `Operator` as an abstract base class, and then the "Calculator" holds a polymorphic container of `Operator*` with an instance of operations supported, so then it can just call `evaluate` on an Operator just by matching the ID.

```
class Operator {
public:
    virtual int evaluate(int left, int right) = 0;

protected:
    const char ID;
    const int precedence;
};

class Multiplication : public Operator {
public:
    Multiplication() {
        ID = '*';
        precedence = 2;
    }
    virtual int evaluate(int left, int right) {
        return left * right;
    }
};

class Addition : public Operator {
public:
    Addition() {
        ID = '+';
        precedence = 1;
    }
    virtual int evaluate(int left, int right) {
        return left + right;
    }
};

// etc.
```

Also, I'm a little concerned about how I am initializing the constants, but that is not my primary question.

Comment: Allow it to be instantiated more than once? Although if the class is just the core functionality of the program, you might as well just make it the `main` logic. No sense in over-engineering.

Comment: *This seems like horrible structure and bad OOP, so how what do I replace it with?* Did you have bad experience with the posted code? If not, what made you think that?

Comment: @RSahu Well I was concerned, because it seems like if I am defining an object, it should be a _thing_ that has data associated with each instance. Here, every instance would be identical, which worries me, but I couldn't see any other way since I needed to change implementation of `evaluate`.

Comment: @Aposhian You don't *have* to make many instances, so why worry?

Comment: On the other hand, do these operations really need to be *types*? I would implement a binary operator type, and have different instances for the different arithmetic operations.

Comment: @juanchopanza Are you referring to making the class more specific to binary operations? Because I originally was using templates to support unary and binary operations, but removed that for my prototype. Or are you referring to a different kind of implementation which I am not familiar with?

Comment: You should probably use public inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in a comment:

> Well I was concerned, because it seems like if I am defining an object, it should be a thing that has data associated with each instance. Here, every instance would be identical, which worries me, but I couldn't see any other way since I needed to change implementation of `evaluate`.

Yes, the data are identical for each object. That's a good observation. When the data are identical for each object, it's good idea to turn them into `static` member data and/or provide access to them through functions, `virtual` functions when it is appropriate.

Here's a version of your posted code that removes the member data and provides `virtual` functions to access them. This also obviates the need to have explicit constructors.

```
class Operator {
   public:
      virtual int evaluate(int left, int right) = 0;
      virtual char getID() const = 0;
      virtual int getPrecedence() const = 0;
};

class Multiplication : Operator {
   public:
      virtual char getID() const
      {
         return '*';
      }

      virtual int getPrecedence() const
      {
         return 2;
      }

      virtual int evaluate(int left, int right) {
         return left * right;
      }
};

class Addition : Operator {
   public:
      virtual char getID() const
      {
         return '+';
      }

      virtual int getPrecedence() const
      {
         return 1;
      }
      virtual int evaluate(int left, int right) {
         return left + right;
      }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a great option to use std::function:

```
class Operator{
    public: //just for demonstration
    const char ID;
    const int precedence;
    std::function<int(int,int)> func;
}

//in main:
Operator Multiplication{
    '*',
    2,
    [](int a, int b){return a*b;}
};
```

The idea here is this:

Make `Operator` a class that stores a std::function or a function pointer. Then make Addition, Multiplication and so on instances of the class and pass each instance its own std::function (here i used a lambda, but you might use a normal function as well). Of course this only works if the signatures of all functions are identical, but from your example it seems they are.